# Integrating Polymer Web Components into React app written in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, polymer, web-component, google-web-component

Trying to integrate a Polymer Web Components tooltip feature into a React App written in TypeScript.

On compile, it is throwing error `Property 'paper-tooltip' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'`

So, trying to get the `<paper-toooltip>` into the JSX namespace, I created this file:

`Tooltip.txs`:

```
import * as React from 'react'

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinisicElements {
            'paper-tooltip': { Tooltip: string }
        }
    }
}

export default Tooltip;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I understand in React/TypeScript there is issue with components are required to start with capital letter, like "I" … this is adding to my confusion, I don't understand.

Comment: Could you please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I'm still working on this. Will open the project soon and try some of the suggestions here and report back. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo. You wrote `IntrinisicElements` instead of `IntrinsicElements` when merging the interface.

```
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            'paper-tooltip': { Tooltip: string }
        }
    }
}
```

From my testing, this was the only issue, but if that was just a typo when pasting the question, it's probably an issue with config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue may be the `-` in the component name `paper-clip`.  You cannot include a `-` in component names because when initializing the component it breaks Javascript variable naming conventions: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

```
// invalid variable name
const paper-clip = ()=> {
  // return JSX here
}
```

So, either you are declaring `paper-clip` incorrectly, or it is not a component.